Plant idenitfication:
Stems mostly red with green; leaves are green, pointed oval with a "pair of purple open wings" midway across leaf. Flower stalk similar to plantain flower stalks, but grow along the stems

Hi Sue, and welcome to the site.  If you could add a picture it would help a lot.  You would have to edit the picture into your post, here is a how-to.

It would also help if you told us what area of the world the plant lives in - hardiness zone is especially helpful for US/UK IDs.

Plantain, like the banana? Plantain the hardy weed?
